# Выбрать максимальный элемент из словаря в Python 3

Tags: python

Код такой:

```
PC = {
'MAC': {'CPU': 2500, 'GPU': 1024, 'DDR3': 4000},
'Intel': {'CPU': 1800, 'GPU': 512, 'DDR3': 3000},
'AMD': {'CPU': 1500, 'GPU': 256, 'DDR3': 2000},
}
```

Из этого словаря нужно выбрать максимальный элемент с учетом параметров ключ-значение. Понимаю, что здесь можно всё сделать путем простых математических выражений или через функцию max. Но как конкретно реализовать - ну не помню. Через "print" должно вывести название элемента с максимальным значением.

Comment: А что именно должно быть максимальным? CPU, GPU, DDR3 или все три критерия нужно просуммировать?

Comment: А вообще - гуглите в сторону использования параметра key функции max. Ну или простым циклом вы могли бы решить вашу задачу быстрее, чем задавать вопрос и ждать ответа.

Comment: Нужно вывести только наименование элемента словаря с наибольшей мощностью (MAC, Intel, AMD). К примеру, print ('Наибольшую мощность имеет', ...) и далее название элемента словаря (мак, интел или амд). Через sum это же можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Готово:

```
PC = {'MAC': {'CPU': 2500, 'GPU': 1024, 'DDR3': 4000},
      'Intel': {'CPU': 1800, 'GPU': 512, 'DDR3': 3000},
      'AMD': {'CPU': 1500, 'GPU': 256, 'DDR3': 2000},
}
print(tuple(max(((itm[0], itm[1][key]) for itm in PC.items()), key=lambda t: t[1]) for key in set(sum((tuple(d.keys()) for d in PC.values()), ()))))
```

Comment: Andrio, спасибо за напоминание! Только 1 вопрос, А если нужно вывести только наименование элемента словаря с наибольшей мощностью (MAC, Intel, AMD) - это через функцию sum?

Comment: сменить `max(((itm[0], itm[1][key]) for itm in PC.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])` на `max(((itm[0], itm[1][key]) for itm in PC.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])[0]`